# Find all natural numbers *a*, that satisfy the following:

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math

Find all natural numbers $a$ Such that :
$$
\frac{a^4+4}{17}
$$
is prime.

Comment: sorry for the misleading tag, I've just fixed it.

Comment: Start by figuring out when your expression is an integer. What condition do you need on $a$ for this?

Answer (score 7):

**Hint:** If the number
$$\frac{a^4+4}{17}=\frac{(a^2-2a+2)(a^2+2a+2)}{17}$$
is prime, then one of $a^2-2a+2$ and $a^2+2a+2$ must be ...

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I'm not exactly sure what do you mean now. Could you clarify your idea?

Comment: I'll just say this: what can the prime factorizations of the integers $a^2-2a+2$ and $a^2+2a+2$ look like? (By the way, you really have to show your work in future questions. People aren't as inclined to help if you haven't demonstrated any effort or progress yourself.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I have one more question - I think I solved the problem. Is the correct answer: for n=5 and for n=3?
Thank you again for help :)